# Jquery and Ajax delete confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i need help with this one. I have my function working well with ajax, but i need a ok / cancel delete  confirmation box before i send ajax request in order to remove item from database. This is my code:

```
delete_article = function(article_id){
     $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/article/delete_article",
           data: "article_id="+article_id,
           asynchronous: true,
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function(){

           },
          success: function(){
              $('#articletr'+article_id).hide();

          }

         });
    }
})
```

Comment: cache is misspelled

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete from the database?");
if (answer)
{
     // your ajax code
}
```

If you want more control over these kinds of modal dialog prompts with JQuery (buttons that say something other than OK/cancel, more than two buttons, or different styles), you can use [JQuery UI Modal Confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Comment: You got to be kidding me. Why are we writing the same answer at the same time. I give up. You get the reputation. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the builtin javascript method `confirm`:

```
if (confirm("Really send?")) {
    // Do it!
}
```

Since those native browser dialogs have a very ugly history and can not be styled at all they are often avoided in favour of other methods. A great examples is the [Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) of [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)